# Network troubles with installing SecurePlatform on Hyper-V VM

Tags: ethernet, hyper-v, checkpoint

I try to install check point SecurePlatform on my Hyper-V virtual machine.
I have two virtual swithes, External and Internal, and two Ethernet adapters in my VM settings. But I don't see any Ethernet adapters in Device scan list during SecurePlatform installation process.

I have not any idea, why it happens. I think that SecurePlatform doesn't support virtualization, but I can't find any information about it compability with Hyper-V hypervisor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution: I need to create two legacy network adapters for both virtual switches. Now I can ping SecurePlatform machine from my virtual internal network.

Also you need https connection to interact with webui from client machine.